# How to Execute two update panels in a page Asynchronously at a time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel

i have 2 update panels in asp.net page with in update panel one textbox and asp button available ,the user enter the textboxes and click the buttons one after another ,the first request send to one class method (it taking 5sec time) and second request send another class method(it take 10sec time)but now the user click the firstbutton without waiting response immediately click second button , **i have send both requests and display the response independently (that means asynchronously)** pls give me any suggestion

Comment: Why don't you disable the seconde button and enable it when the first asynch request complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UpdateProgress control:

[Update Process](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```